# Sidebar cart shows incorrect price when adding a bundle product to the cart twice in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I encountered a strange behavior on my Magento (1.7.0.2) installation.

When I add a bundle product with the same configuration (bundle options) to the cart twice, then the cart in the sidebar shows a wrong price. The wrong price looks totally odd to me and makes no sense.

E.g: When I add a product which costs $ 6.25 and add it another time then the price in the cart is $ 23.36 although it should be $ 12.50.

When I then browse to the normal cart, the price is shown correctly and when I browse back to a product page where the sidebar cart is shown then it also shows the correct price.

The strange behavior only occurs for bundle products with the exact same configuration. I haven't tested all product types, but simple products don't lead to this error.

Furthermore it doesn't matter when the product is added a second time. The error also occurs when I add a different product to the cart in between.

The error doesn't raise when I add two products at once by setting the quantity to 2, then everything is ok. For me it seems as there's something going wrong when Magento tries to merge the two products with the identical configuration in the cart.

Any suggestion what might cause this problem?

Comment: What are the prices of your configurable options? I have a feeling the bundle pricing stuff in 1.7.0.2 is buggy. Bundle products have two prices, max and min based on the highest and lowest possible configurable prices. I've found that when you add several configurable items to a bundle, Magento calculates the tax in an odd way, which seems to ignore the row/unit/item setting. 


Add a tier price discount or special price and there seems to be all sorts of rounding errors.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. I didn't have much time in the last weeks to dive deeper in this issue

Comment: @Flo were you able to manage this issue, I am facing same issue in EE 1.12